# How to use golang build commands in gradle

Tags: go, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to write buildscript in gradle for a simple golang web application.

Can someone please tell me how to use golang commands for build and install in gradle build?

I do not see any clear documentation for the usage of gradle for a go lang application.

Comment: go is designed for "all in one" I suppose. all sources and libraries in `GOPATH` in compile time. all libraries compiled in to the executable in run time. That means go not need a build system

Answer (score 2):

Try Gogradle https://github.com/blindpirate/gogradle, a full-featured Golang build plugin.

What you need to do is creating a `build.gradle` as documented, and run `./gradlew build` or `./gradlew test`.

Comment: Please don't just post a link to some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate how it solves the problem in the answer itself.

Comment: It is demostrated in the link. I think I shouldn't put code here because they may be out-of-date and mislead people.

Answer (score 0):

gradle supports maven plugins and you can just call [the mvn-golang maven plugin](https://github.com/raydac/mvn-golang) as usual maven plugin published in the maven central